# Are least squares equivalent to ML normal distribution for any $f$?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares

I know that it's true if the model is linear and about least squares to non-linear models?

I mean:

$LS=argmin_{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i-f(x_i,\beta))^2$ , where $x_i\in \Re^n$

is equivalent to:

$ML=argmax_{\theta}\prod_{i=1}^{N}\phi(y_i,f(x_i,\beta),\sigma)$, where $\phi$ is normal distribution function and $y_i\sim N(f(x_i,\beta),\sigma)$

for any $f\in \mathcal{F}$. Note i didnt use multivariate normal function even $x_i \in \Re^n$.

Comment: Take the negative logarithm of ML and draw the conclusion.